# Archive::Zip membersMatching can't locate method in Perl?

Tags: perl, methods, archive, perl-module

I have a script that uses `Archive::Zip`, and I want to use the method `membersMatching`,  but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

I called the module at the beginning of the script:

```
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS :MISC_CONSTANTS );
```

and this is the block of code where the module is used:

```
while (my $file = readdir(TRIMMED_CELL_DIR)) {

    #Only if file ends in _1.fastqc.zip (only 1 instance per "trimmed" subdirectory.)
    if($file =~ /.*\_1\_fastqc\.zip/){  

        #Extract the file summary.txt and assign it to filehandle SUMMARY_R1.
        $file = "${trimmedDirectory}/${file}";
        print "Loading ZIP file: $file. \n";
        my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($file);
        my @txtFileMembers = $zip->membersMatching( '.*\.txt' );
        foreach my $txtFile (@txtFileMembers){
            extractMember($txtFile);
            open(SUMMARY_R1,"< $txtFile");
        }

    }
```

I keep getting the error `Can't locate object method "membersMatching".` ... and I know it has something to do with this membersMatching method not being exported, but I don't know how to call it in the script. Te CPAN page for Archive::Zip doesn't say anything except to use it like so:

> membersMatching( $regex )
>   membersMatching( { regex => $regex } )
>   Return array of members whose filenames match given regular expression in list context. Returns number of matching members in
>   scalar context.
>
> ```
>     my @textFileMembers = $zip->membersMatching( '.*\.txt' );
>     # or
>     my $numberOfTextFiles = $zip->membersMatching( '.*\.txt' );
> ```

The ZIP file loading with the `Archive::Zip->new($file)` function works, so the module is being exported, just not the method `memebersMatching`...

Comment: What is the rest of your error message? It must also say `via package "Xxx" `

Answer (score 1):

Check the path of your zip file (`$file`). I think it's failing there. Update your code to the below:

```
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
unless ( $zip->read( 'someZip.zip' ) == AZ_OK ) {
    die 'read error';
}

print "zip contains the following files:\n";
print "$_\n" for $zip->memberNames();
```